# Parse image link into image HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need your help.
Im coding chat app and have problem with one function.
I need to parse image link into HTML image tag.
For example:
User is posting link to image:

```
https://www.lehigh.edu/google/google_search.png
```

And i want to parse it into:

```
<img src="https://www.lehigh.edu/google/google_search.png" height="50px">
```

I treid many regex but without success.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's wrong with string concatenation ?

Comment: You need to parse src attribute from img tag ?

Comment: `$imageLink = '<img src="'.$postLink.'" height="50px">';` Something like this.

Comment: so, all what you need is parse link from chat message? for example, user post "hello all, this is my image http://domain/image.gif' ?